# Making an App that requires constant current location

Tags: android

I am trying to design an app which requires current location of the user time and again. So, whenever cellular data is available, i use mobile network to get the current user location. If mobile network is not available, can I reliably use GPS to get access to current location. If not, can anyone suggest what should I do in such cases?
Edit: Location services doesn't work very well. I already tried using it.

Comment: Go with [Location Client](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)... Useful to get Current Location.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at Android Location APIs:
 https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Android uses what they call Fused location provider. It is Android (through Google play services) responsability to choose which provider (GPS, sensors, WIFI fingerprinting...) is best each time to get current user location.

I think it is a great technology and APIs are really simple to use

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Docs:

> Knowing where the user is allows your application to be smarter and deliver better information to the user. When developing a location-aware application for Android, you can utilize GPS and Android's Network Location Provider to acquire the user location. Although GPS is most accurate, it only works outdoors, it quickly consumes battery power, and doesn't return the location as quickly as users want. Android's Network Location Provider determines user location using cell tower and Wi-Fi signals, providing location information in a way that works indoors and outdoors, responds faster, and uses less battery power. To obtain the user location in your application, you can use both GPS and the Network Location Provider, or just one.

If you want more detail you can take a look at :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

yes If there is no Network available then you can go for GPS but we must use it smartly and efficiently
because GPS give much accurate location than network, but it reduce the battery life and also you can use Pending Intent for getting location and broadcast receiver at the place of Location Listener

but I suggest you this link with light this topic in much detail

[These are some smart coding concepts for increasing battery life](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html)